# Windows + Space no longer working in spectrwm since Eoan Ermine 19.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, window-manager

Since the last upgrade to Eoan Ermine (19.10), I can no longer use the "Windows-Key + Spacebar" shortcut to change the stacking layout in the [spectrwm](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/conformal/spectrwm/blob/master/spectrwm.html) window manager.

I guess that Ubuntu is capturing this key combination, but can't find a place to turn it off.

Comment: keyboard shortcuts under system settings.. you can disable it.

Comment: I found it under "switch to next input source" and disabled it, but it doesn't seem to work...